# How to Open a New Tab to a Specific Webpage in Firefox 57.0.2?

Tags: firefox

There is no *browser.newtab* section like writed [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/284582/how-to-open-a-new-tab-to-a-specific-webpage-in-your-browser/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1162532) in the mozilla support forum suggests to use a browser extension for this purpose.

One of the two examples mentioned is [new tab override](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/).